# How to get the custom ROM/Android OS Name from Android programatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin, harmonyos

I wish to receive the custom ROM/Android OS name from device e.g. Let’s say if device is:

**Oppo** -> *ColorOS*

**OnePlus** -> *OxygenOS*

**Huawei** -> *HarmonyOS*

I've used the following methods also, but no success.

`Build.DISPLAY` -> *ONEPLUS A6003_22_201116*

`Build.VERSION.BASE_OS` -> "" // returns empty string

`System.getProperty("os.name")`  -> *Linux*

`System.getProperty("os.version")` -> *4.9.179-perf+*

`System.getProperty("ro.modversion")`  -> *null* // returns null

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to check and get HarmonyOS:

```
public static boolean isHarmony(Context context) {
    try {
        int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("config_os_brand", "string", "android");
        return context.getString(id).equals("harmony");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```